# Column Name, Row Number of a Defined Name

Tags: vba, excel, names

I want to know the command to find the Column name of a Defined name and a row number of a defined name in vba. So if B3 is named Candy, i search for Candy and return column B. I google for an hour and couldn't find an answer.

I'm going to use those column name and row number to get data from the intersection and extract it into another worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a worksheet and a named range that's in it to this sub and it will print the range's address and first `Column` and first `Row` to the Immediate Window. If the range is more than one cell, it will also print the last column and row:

```
Sub PrintNameRowAndCol(ws As Excel.Worksheet, strName As String)
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim SplitAddress As Variant

On Error Resume Next
Set rng = ws.Range(strName)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Debug.Print rng.Address
    SplitAddress = Split(rng.Address, "$")
    Debug.Print "Column: "; SplitAddress(1)
    Debug.Print "Row: "; SplitAddress(2)
If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then
    Debug.Print "Last Column: "; SplitAddress(3)
    Debug.Print "Last Row: "; SplitAddress(4)
End If
End If
End Sub
```

If there is no range with that name, nothing happens.

The routine uses the `Split` function which breaks a string into an array based on a delimiter, "$" in this case. Since the Range's `Address` property returns a string in the absolute reference format, i.e., $Column$Row, the Split function always returns an array with two elements, the column and row, for a single-cell range. For a multiple cell range it returns four elements.

Call it like this:

```
Sub test()
PrintNameRowAndCol ActiveSheet, "Candy"
End Sub
```

EDIT: In answer to your specific question in the comments, you don't really need to figure the column letters and row numbers of the two ranges. In order to get the contents of the intersection of the column of one range and the row of another, and then assign it to a 3rd range, do something like this:

```
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("D12") = .Cells(.Range("Cost").Row, .Range("Candy").Column)
End With
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to take the results and plug it right back into another code.

Comment: There is. As mentioned in your earlier question, being more specific in your question will get you an answer you can use. Please modify your question to show the code that this would be plugged into. (Or just accept my answer and see if you can figure it out yourself :) )

Comment: Ok! Candy is in B3, and Cost is in A12. Let say B12 = 100. I want the find the intersection and put the answer from that into d12. Thank you so much again.

Comment: You are persistent! In the future please modify the actual question, don't add to it in the comments. At any rate I edited my answer. Now that I know more about what you're doing, it seems over-complicated, even with the simplification I added. This seems like a complex way to just copy the contents of a cell two columns over.

Comment: I'm going to be using the vba to extract information from multiple worksheets where the information is scattered. Usually the names  in the column and rows are different so I will set a Defined name to each. I'm still a novice at vba, currently using excel 2010 power programming for vba to learn.